# How to remove specific String stored in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a code which stores the values for later use. But I need to find the exact names and not the whole. I am getting output like below:

Output result shows: `[ Ranjit Nayak ( Attorney ), ranjti Nyak ( Case Manager ), shenoy attorney ( Parallegal ) ]`

So I need to use some method to remove content including brackets. Please help.

In the code: `CaseManagersreceivingreminders` is a global `ArrayList`, I have a similar another `ArrayList` stored values. Once the string is edited successfully I need to compare both the array values.

Tried `trim`, `replace`. Nothing works.

```
    List<WebElement> PMPageCMList =
        driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='collapseCM']/div[2]/div[2]/div"));

    int totalcms = PMPageCMList.size();
    for (int i = 1; i <= totalcms; i++) {
        CaseManagersreceivingreminders.add(
            driver
                .findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='collapseCM']/div[2]/div[2]/div" + "[" + i + "]" + "/span"))
                .getText()
        );
    }

    Collections.sort(CaseManagersreceivingreminders);
    Collections.sort(ReminderCMsList);

    try {
        boolean isEqual = CaseManagersreceivingreminders.contains(ReminderCMsList);
        System.out.println(isEqual);
        Log.pass("Data matching" + isEqual);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I should get the output like: `[ Ranjit Nayak, ranjti Nyak, shenoy attorney ]`

Comment: then you have to walk through each element of the array and replace the element with the modified one. Where is the problem now? Or just create a new array based on the new elements, doesn't matter here for small arrays

Comment: @AKSW sample code please!

Comment: How can `split()` and `trim()` related to Selenium? Am I missing something?

Comment: You should stick to the Java Naming Conventions: variable names are always written in camelCase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to remove `(...)` part of the String:

```
List<String> newList =  new ArrayList<>();

for(String s: CaseManagersreceivingreminders) {
    s = s.replaceAll("\\(.*\\)", "");
    newList.add(s);
}

System.out.println(newList);
```

Output:

`[Ranjit Nayak, ranjti Nyak, shenoy attorney]`

About `\\(.*\\)` regex:

- `\\(` and `\\)` :  For any special characters like `(` or `)` you
  should use `\\` before them to match.
- `.*` : Matches any character zero or more times.

Thus `\\(.*\\)` expression can match part of a string like `( Attorney )`

Answer (score 0):

Your `Collection` `CaseManagersreceivingreminders` is a list of strings, so just iterate over the list, for each string split over `'('` and save the new strings in a new list.

```
for (String names : CaseManagersreceivingreminders) {
    CaseManagersreceivingreminders_New.add(names.split("(")[0]);
}
```

Comment: but this will only remove 1st (, how about the content inside the bracket?

Comment: @ranjitnayak "Ranjit Nayak ( Attorney )".split("(") will split the string into two strings "Ranjit Nayak " and  " Attorney )" .

Read more about split() method here  -https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.UnaryOperator)) method of [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html), with a suitable [`UnaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/UnaryOperator.html):

```
list.replaceAll(s -> s.replaceAll(" *[(].+?[)]", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `(...)` part from each string using the following regex: `\s*\(.*\)`

If you want to update the existing list you can use `List.replaceAll()`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*\\(.*\\)");
list.replaceAll(s -> pattern.matcher(s).replaceAll(""));
```

Alternatively you can use Java Streams if you want to create a new list with the results:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*\\(.*\\)");
List<String> result = list.stream()
        .map(s -> pattern.matcher(s).replaceAll(""))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```